# Delete Query Statement issue

Tags: sql, date, sql-delete

In the "**created**" attribute I memorize the date of creation, which is of type:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

I want to create a query which deletes rows WHERE created is greater than a value.

I tried this version:

```
DELETE FROM tasks 
WHERE projectid ='1182' AND assignerid ='48' AND created BETWEEN DATE(2014-06-10) AND DATE(2014-07-16)
```

or

```
DELETE FROM tasks 
WHERE projectid ='1182' AND assignerid ='48' AND created > #2014-06-10 00:00:00#
```

But neither of them is not working. What should I do?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Use ANSI for dates `'20140610'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect delimiter, use `'` for date.

```
DELETE FROM tasks 
WHERE projectid ='1182' AND assignerid ='48' AND created > '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
```